# DIP switches and IC inputs

Tags: microcontroller, switches

I am trying to connect a DIP switch (A6A-16R specifically) to some MCU IO pins. From looking at a reference schematic, they connected the Com line to GND. I was curious how that works? Shouldn't it be connected to VCC so that if the dip switch is 'ON,' the respective MCU input is high? If 'off' it'll be floating (When the PCB is on/active, the DIP switches wont be moved so floating shouldn't affect it)?

My thinking is that connecting 'Com' to gnd makes everything 0 or floating (floating from gnd so still gnd?) regardless since the IO pin is being used as an input? I don't see it as sinking the pin since then it would be 0 if 'on' and floating if 'off' but then the pin wouldn't be able to read since its being used as an output.

Was this maybe a typo on the reference schematic?

Comment: I searched "Using switches with microcontrollers" and the first search result is [this](https://www.w9xt.com/page_microdesign_pt6_switch_inputs.html) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never leave the input of an MCU floating. Then any noise will change it between high or low, you never know which.

But it is very common to have all types of switches connect to ground. Then you have a pull-up resistor connected to (or often om modern MCU's, built into the MCU pin and enabled via software) the input. Then the input reads high when the switch is not actuated, and low when it is, grounding the pull-up resistor.

It can of course be done the other way around. Having the switch connected to Vcc and then use a pull-down resistor to ground. But having the switch connected to ground is the most common setup.

Comment: So in the schematic, its just the pins from the IO to the DIP. I don't see a pull up resistor (or power supply). So does that mean it's built into the MCU pin (I guess one can assume)?

So in this case, it would be active low (since when the DIP is active, the pin would go low)?

Comment: @bchang32 Many MCUs have optional internal pull-ups and/or pull-downs.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect it in any way you want. This is not specific yo DIP switches as this is a more genral problem, discussed many times already.

ON could either connect to ground or to VCC, but OFF state can't leave a pin floating.

So depending on what kind of internal resistors your MCU has, you can do it with internal pull resistors, but some MCUs only have internal pull-ups, so external pull-ups may not be necessary.

You can put external pull resistors to VCC or GND to keep state when DIP is OFF.